# Mysql complex sorting by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following MySQL db table filled with data:

```
|id|parentId|position
|20|NULL    |1
|21|NULL    |2
|22|NULL    |3
|23|21      |1
|24|21      |2
```

Is it possible to sort it to get final result as:

```
|id|parentId|position
|20|NULL    |1
|21|NULL    |2
|23|21      |1
|24|21      |2
|22|NULL    |3
```

As you may notice, position inside parent starts from 1.

So I want it sorted by three columns: id, parentId and position. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something ?

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(parentId, id), parentId, position
```

Answer (score 3):

The sorting logic you want is to sort first by the `parentId` group.  This can be obtained using `COALESCE(parentId, id)`.  In other words, if the `parentId` is present, then use it, otherwise take the `id`, which must also be the parent.  Then, within parent group, sort NULLs first.  Finally, within those two groups, sort by position.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(parentId, id),
    parentID,
    position;
```

[image]

### Demo